# Enumerable.SequenceEqual<TSource> and EqualityComparer<T>

Tags: .net, linq, msdn, enumerable, iequalitycomparer

From  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx%3a)

> The
>   SequenceEqual(IEnumerable,
>   IEnumerable) method
>   enumerates the two source sequences in
>   parallel and compares corresponding
>   elements by using the default equality
>   comparer for TSource, Default. The
>   default equality comparer, Default, is
>   used to compare values of the types
>   that implement the
>   IEqualityComparer generic
>   interface.

a) As I understand the above quote, it's implying that `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` is used to compare elements of types that implement the `IEqualityComparer<T>`, when in fact  `Default` is used to return a particular implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>` that either calls `IEquatable<T>.Equals` (assuming `T` is assignable to `IEquatable<T>` ) or it calls `Object.Equals`

b) Quote also suggests that `TSource` must implement `IEqualityComparer<T>`, which isn't true:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        Test test1 = new Test();
        Test test2 = new Test();

        Test[] list1 = { test1, test2 };
        Test[] list2 = { test1, test2 };

        bool eq = list1.SequenceEqual(list2); //works
   }     

  public class Test { }
```

So did I misinterpret what the quote is trying to convey or is the quote plain wrong?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not `TSource` should implement `IEqualityComparer`

But `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` implements `IEqualityComparer`

> The default equality **comparer**, Default, is used to compare values of the types **that implement** the IEqualityComparer generic interface.

That's too oblivious to be mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx):

> The Default property checks whether
>   type T implements the
>   System.IEquatable interface and, if
>   so, returns an EqualityComparer
>   that uses that implementation.
>   **Otherwise, it returns an EqualityComparer that uses the
>   overrides of Object.Equals and
>   Object.GetHashCode provided by T.**

In your example case it just uses reference equality which is the default equality implementation for reference objects.

Comment: hi. I wasn't asking how equality implementation works in my example. Instead, I was asking whether quote is wrong or whether I misunderstood what it is trying to say

Comment: mhh looking at it closely I agree with you, that last sentence in your quote looks wrong, misleading at best.